# Visual Studio 2010 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017

So i'm doing this project for my Computer Programming Class (That's due tomorrow) and i'm basically done with everything. Our school has Visual Studio 2010, and I have Visual Studio 2017. However, when I open it, it asks me to change to ".NET Framework 4.6.1" as my computer doesn't have ".Net Framework =v4.0". When I do, I can edit the program, but I can't debug/compile the program, as it outputs this error:

The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this, instal the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version... Therefore your assembly may not be correctly trageted for the framework you intend.

However, when I tried to go online and install the v4.6.1, the installer said that I had already had a version of 4.6.1 or a more updated version on my computer. I don't understand why this is, and if there's another question like this it would be helpful if you could link it as a reply. Thanks.

Comment: In VS2017, change target .Net Framework to `.Net 3.5`. You can't target higher than 3.5 with VS 2010.

Comment: @zaitsman visual studio 2010 can do .net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is directly in the error message. "To resolve this, instal the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version."

My advice: **Download and install .NET 4.0 SDK on your computer.**

You can try one of these links to get the SDK:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442

You can also try the multi-targeting pack.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29052

Answer (score 0):

Also, checkout:

1. You can use the setup verification tool to diagnose your .Net Framework here: [.Net Framework Setup Verification Tool](http://cid-27e6a35d1a492af7.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Blog%7C_Tools/netfx%7C_setupverifier%7C_new.zip) or [Alternative Download](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/05/netfx_setupverifier_new.zip).
2. Also check the [.NET Framework Setup Verification Tool User’s Guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/10/13/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide/)
3. If you do find problems with your .Net Framework, you can use the Repair Tool to fix it, it is designed to fix issues specifically concerning the .Net Framework as well as updates: [Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135)

Hope this will be useful, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2017 to support .NET 4.0, you need to make sure you've installed the correct component:

[image: VS2017 installer showing .NET 4 targeting pack]